# How to read a portion of a file in Elixir (or Erlang)?

Tags: file, erlang, elixir, partial

How can we read only a selected portion of a file?

Like this: `Read(file, start, length)`

Comment: Would be handy if read(file, start, length) was part of the File module

Comment: Submit a PR.  The Elixir community is very welcoming to PR's.

Comment: The idea of adding this to `File` was [rejected in 2014](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/2809#issuecomment-58339867) in favour of [`:file.pread/3`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#pread-3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be the code that Hynek shared transcribed to Elixir. I only post it as an answer because it's a bit long to put into a comment.

```
def read(file, start, length) do
  {ok, f} = :file.open(file, [:binary])
  {ok, data} = :file.pread(f, start, length)
  :file.close(f)
  data
end
```

Yes, granted it'd be nice to have this in the Elixir file module.  If you really want it there @CharlesO, why don't you go ahead and create a pull request? Jose and the other core committers are some of the friendliest folks I've run across in years and years of software development.

Comment: The idea of adding `pread` to Elixir [was rejected by José in 2014](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/2809#issuecomment-58339867).

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I read the specific complaint to be more about the side effect of opening the file and closing it each invocation; from an API design perspective that's probably unwanted. I imagine an alternative implementation that takes a file handle as a parameter, instead of a path, and delegates to `:file.pread/3` might go over better. It might belong in the IO module instead, though. (On the other hand, even there the docs reference using :file.position for a similar use case)

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`:file.position/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#position-2) and [`:file.read/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#read-2).

With:

```
$ seq 10 > 10.txt
```

and code:

```
{:ok, file} = :file.open("10.txt", [:read, :binary])
:file.position(file, 5)
IO.inspect :file.read(file, 10)
```

The output is:

```
{:ok, "\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8"}
```

That's 10 bytes starting at the 6th byte.

Answer (score 5):

It would be handy if you read the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/index.html). For example [`file:pread/2,3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#pread-2).

```
read(File, Start, Length) ->
    {ok, F} = file:open(File, [binary]),
    try file:pread(F, [{Start, Length}]) of
        {ok, [Data]} -> Data
    after file:close(F)
    end.
```

Comment: Thanks. My comment refers to the Elixir File module.

Comment: @CharlesO Oh, I didn't know. I don't use Elixir. I think PR could be accepted.

Comment: It's not that hard to transcribe your code into Elixir @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil.  In fact I've transcribed it and posted it below.