# How to do an lseek on an open file, and read N bytes?

Tags: data-structures, io, elixir, file-access, lseek

I'd like to use Elixir to read a binary file that has a fixed-length header, and data structures within that are of determinable length. These files can be huge, and I *really* don't want to be forced to read the entire thing to memory. Maybe my search-fu is lacking, but I didn't find anything like this in the docs or elsewhere.

Comment: I am not that familiar with Elixir yet, but it seems to me that this tread still has the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121605/how-to-read-a-portion-of-a-file-in-elixir-or-erlang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [File](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#module-seeking-within-a-file) docs:

> to read
> from a specific position in a file, use `:file.pread/3`:
>
> ```elixir
> File.write!("example.txt", "Eats, Shoots & Leaves")
> file = File.open!("example.txt")
> :file.pread(file, 15, 6)
> #=> {:ok, "Leaves"}
> ```
>
> Alternatively, if you need to keep track of the current position, use
> `:file.position/2` and `:file.read/2`:
>
> ```elixir
> :file.position(file, 6)
> #=> {:ok, 6}
> :file.read(file, 6)
> #=> {:ok, "Shoots"}
> :file.position(file, {:cur, -12})
> #=> {:ok, 0}
> :file.read(file, 4)
> #=> {:ok, "Eats"}
> ```